# Unable to display data from relationships in templates

Tags: java, playframework, twirl

I'm stuck with trying to display data for a One-to-One relationship in Twirl templates (using Play Framework Java - 2.5.10). Basically I have a User model:

```
package models;

import java.sql.Date;
import javax.persistence.*;
import com.avaje.ebean.Model;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends Model {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    public String firstName;

    @Column(name = "middle_name")
    public String middleName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    public String lastName;

    @Column(name = "date_of_birth")
    public Date dateOfBirth;

    @Column(name = "sex")
    public String sex;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "time_zone_id")
    public TimeZone timeZone;

    public static Finder<Long, User> find = new Finder<>(User.class);
}
```

and the Farmer model:

```
package models;

import com.avaje.ebean.Model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name="farmers")
public class Farmer extends Model {
    public enum Status {INACTIVE, ACTIVE}

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    public Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    public User user;

    @Column(name="profile_pic_url")
    public String profilePicUrl;

    @Column(name="access_url")
    public String accessUrl;

    @Column(name="status")
    public String status = Status.INACTIVE.name();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "farmer", targetEntity = Farm.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<Farm> farms;

    public static Finder<Long, Farmer> find = new Finder<>(Farmer.class);

    public static List<Farmer> getAllActive() {
        return Farmer.find.where().eq("status", Status.ACTIVE.name()).findList();
    }
}
```

Notice there's a one-to-one with User model with fetch type set to eager. Now, I want to display data of farmers in my template, where a farmer's name is actually the name in the associated User model.

So I did this in my controller:

```
public class FarmerController extends Controller {
    public Result all() {
        return ok(farmers.render(Farmer.getAllActive()));
    }
    public Result farmer(Long id, String url) {
        return ok(farmer.render());
    }
}
```

Now this gets me the right farmer data, but when I try to display the name via the User model, I get null. More specifically, writing this results in nulls (I get `nullnull`, actually):

```
<div><h4>@(farmer.user.firstName + farmer.user.lastName)</h4></div>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using [play-enhancer](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/PlayEnhancer)? If I remember properly, the model enhancer does not works for views. So, inside your `Farmer` model you have to create a `getUser` method and then adapt your views to use it.

Comment: @marcospereira Hmm, thanks. I'm indeed using the enhancer plugin. While I was able to get my example to work by changing it to `return Farmer.find.fetch("user").where().eq("status", Status.ACTIVE.name()).findList();` I don't think I can keep doing it for traversing long chains of relationships. I haven't called functions from views however, and I hope it's as simple as `@farmer.getUser().firstName()`.

Comment: @marcospereira Thank you, this worked! Could you add this as the answer below so that I can accept? :-) (on a side note, I hate this enhancer plugin - it's being touted as magic in the docs, but just like magic, it doesn't work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed at the comments, this is because play-enhancer does not works for views or any Scala code at all. Since Twirl compiles `scala.html` code to scala code, this compiled code is not touched by the enhancer.

The solution is then to manually create the get for the relationship:

```
public class Farmer extends Model {

    public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

}
```

This is Java code and then will be handled as expected. Of course, you have to change your views to use `farmer.getUser` instead of `farm.user`.

---

Also, as stated at the docs, byte code enhancement involves some magic. But you can avoid it at all and just use regular POJOs (with explicitly declared gets and sets).